# how to stored data from API to react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have try this code to save data from API, no error when i run this code, but data API not save to dataDetail from state

```
class DetailApi extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            dataDetail: {},
        }
    }

    getDetail = ()=>{
        axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.props.nameParam.name}`)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                dataDetail: res.data,
            })
            console.log(res.data)
            console.log(this.state.dataDetail)
        })
    }
```

i expect api data to be stored in state

Comment: And what is the issue? Note, `setState` is an async process. So it will not update immediately. `setState` takes second argument as a function. Try using that. `setState({}, () => console.log(this.state))`

Comment: getDetail = ()=>{
        axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.props.nameParam.name}`)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                dataDetail: res.data,
            }, () => console.log(this.state.dataDetail))
            // console.log(res.data)
            // console.log(this.state.dataDetail)
            
        })
    } this solve my problem, thank you Rajesh

Comment: i'm try to experiment write code like this `getDetail(){
        axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.props.nameParam.name}`)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                dataDetail: res.data,
            })
            console.log(res.data)
            console.log(this.state.dataDetail)
            
        })
    }` why this have same result?